# How can the Möbius function be applied to a series?

Tags: summation, arithmetic-functions

Given a series $p_n(s)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k $. I'd like to get $\hat{p}_n(s)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k)a_k $. Think of $a_k=k^{-s}$ for example. If you let $n$ go to $\infty$, you'll see the well-known relation between $\zeta$ and $1/\zeta$.

May I apply something like a Möbius operator on $p_n(s)$, such that $\mu\circ p=\hat p$?

<strike>The wiki page on the [Primon gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primon_gas) mentions the Fermi operator [$(-1)^F$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28-1%29%5EF), so I thought about the following:
Given a $n$-dimensional vector $\vec a=(a_k)^T$. Let $\vec e=(1,\dots,1)^T$, then $p=\vec e \cdot \vec a$ and $\hat p=\vec e \cdot (\mu \vec a)$, with $\mu$ being a diagonal matrix with entries $\mu_{kk}=\mu(k)$.
Is this a finite dimensional matrix representation of the Fermi operator?</strike>

**EDIT:** The thing is, I don't see why there is on the one hand something like

> Another inversion formula is (where we assume that the series involved are absolutely convergent):
>   $$
>     g(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{f(mx)}{m^s}\quad\mbox{ for all } x\ge 1\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \mu(m)\frac{g(mx)}{m^s}\quad\mbox{ for all } x\ge 1. 
> $$
>   (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations))

further on the other

> The classic version states that if g(n) and f(n) are arithmetic functions satisfying
>   $$
>     g(n)=\sum_{d\,\mid \,n}f(d)\quad\text{for every integer }n\ge 1 
> $$
>   then
>   $$
>     f(n)=\sum_{d\,\mid\, n}\mu(d)g(n/d)\quad\text{for every integer }n\ge 1 
> $$
>   (see [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Statement_of_the_formula))

and on the last hand

> A related inversion formula more useful in combinatorics is as follows: suppose F(x) and G(x) are complex-valued functions defined on the interval [1,∞) such that
>   $$
>     G(x) = \sum_{1 \le n \le x}F(x/n)\quad\mbox{ for all }x\ge 1 
> $$
>   then
>   $$
>     F(x) = \sum_{1 \le n \le x}\mu(n)G(x/n)\quad\mbox{ for all }x\ge 1. 
> $$

None of them fits my needs :-( I want someting like $F(x) = \sum_{1 \le n \le x}\mu(n)G(n)\quad\mbox{ for all }x\ge 1. $

**EDIT:** Peter Sarnak's Or Gil Kalai's work (e.g. [The Depth Of The Möbius Function](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/the-depth-of-the-mobius-function/) or [The AC0 Prime Number Conjecture](http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/the-ac0-prime-number-conjecture/)) shows the right kind of formulas, but I'm not sure if they are talking about what I need: My function $G(n)$ would sent the natural numbers to $be^{ia}$, with $b$ being an integer and not only to $\{-1,1\}$...

Comment: What do you mean by "get" in your first sentence?

Comment: I'd like to start out with $p_n(s)$ and then do something like the Dirichlet convolution without the $d|n$ summation restriction to **get** $\hat p_n(s)$. BTW, it's the second sentence...

Comment: Instead of "Dirichlet convolution" it's rather a Moebius Inversion $\mu * p$ (which is a special kind of Dirichlet convolution), but summed without the $d|n$- restriction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson e.g. the inverse of $\zeta$ would be an example, which sums over infinitely many elements without regarding $d|n$. I'm interested in the finite case.

Comment: "On the one hand ... on the other ... on the last hand". I see you've got three hands, lucky you!

Comment: @marc thanks, can you help me with my question, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do goes against the nature of the Möbius function, so I don't think you are entitled to hope that anything simple and useful could be be said about the operation you describe. I'll explain a bit.

One should think of the Möbius function as a function of *two* integer arguments, $\mu(d,n)$, which represents an (infinite) upper unitriangular matrix $(\mu(d,n))_{d,n\geq1}$ that is the inverse of the matrix $D=([\,d\mid n\,])_{d,n\geq1}$ (the brackets being the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), whose value is $1$ or $0$ according as the divisibilty $d\mid n$ does or does not hold). It happens that $\mu(d,n)$ depends only the value of $n/d$ (because the divisibility interval $\{\,x\in\Bbb N: d\mid x\mid n\,\}$ is isomorphic to $\{\,x\in\Bbb N: 1\mid x\mid n/d\,\}$), so that it can be (and is) written as $\mu(n/d)$, but I consider this an almost accidental circumstance.

The natural thing to do with a matrix is multiplying a vector by it; in this case right multiplication by $D$ applied to an infinite sequence $f=(f(n))_{n\geq1}$ gives
$$
  f\cdot D=(g(n))_{n\geq1} \quad\text{where}\quad g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d),
$$
which operation is the [Dirichlet convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) by the constant sequence $(1)_{n\geq1}$, and right multiplication by $M=(\mu(d,n))_{d,n\geq1}$ is therefore the inverse operation
$$
  g\cdot M=(f(n))_{n\geq1} \quad\text{where}\quad f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}g(d)\mu(d,n),
$$
which operation, due to $\mu(d,n)=\mu(n/d)$, is Dirichlet convolution by the sequence $(\mu(m))_{m\geq1}$.

This gives your middle statement (except that it switches $d$ and $n/d$ which is of course harmless; I prefer to write $\mu(n/d)$ to remind of the matrix nature). For the other two statements, I can see how they follow, but I don't right know see how to get them precisely into this picture, although I get the impression that the first form is related to *left*-multiplication by these matrices, giving rise to infinite sums that somehow are mitigated by the factors $m^{-s}$.

In any case, what you want to do seems like doing a Hadamard product of power series defined to be mutliplicative inverses of something; not easy.